# SSL certificate error with Weblogic in Internet Explorer

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I have a Weblogic server installed and a site. The SSL port is 7002
When I try to access a secure page ex `https://localhost:7002/site` in Internet Explorer I get a certificate error. Clicking the continue to website does not do anything.
In chrome, I get the opton to "Ignore Anyway" and I can continue to see the page. But in Internet explorer I having no such luck. Not sure what I am doing wrong. 
I am using the default certificates that come wih weblogic installation. I have not generated any private keys or certificates.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "a certificate error" — What does the error say?

Comment: Its happening only in Internet Explorer and not on Chrome/Firefox? looks more like a ux.SE question to me.

Comment: When I try to navigate to a https part of the site I get "Certificate error" saying the site is risky to navigate to etc

Comment: Can you share your WebLogic/OS/browser versions? I have just tried the same process over Windows 7, WL 10.3 and both IE8 and Chrome and both worked fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: OP, although this question is waaay old, you should accept suleyman's answer as it worked for me.  I had the exact same problem you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with a recent Windows security update that blocks any site with less than 1024-bit SSL key. WebLogic out of the box comes with 512-bit self signed certificate. If you create your own self-signed identity and key stores with 2048-bit keys the problem will go away.

Comment: would you explain briefly about the self-signed identity creation

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer!  IE and Weblogic both provided me with no valueable exceptions on why this was failing.  Creating a new JKS with a new 2048 bit key did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Suleyman: I am also facing the same problem although I know that this was due to recent microsoft patches. I have disabled those patches and it is working fine now. It would be great if you could share the steps to create 2048-bit keys.

Answer (score 1):

Anil: To create your own SSL key and configure WebLogic to use it, follow the steps here:

http://techworldrocks.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/configure-self-signed-certificate-with-weblogic-server/

Make sure you include '-keysize 2048' on your key generating command

Answer (score 0):

Type in cmd started as administrator:

```
certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512
```

this allows using insecure 512 bit long certificates and should be executed only once on a single host.